# Gradle can't find androidx.compose.compiler - Searches in nodejs.org/dist/v1.2.0-beta02/compiler.jar

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, android-jetpack-compose, bitrise

I am fighting a weird issue with failing gradle builds, and I cannot pinpoint the cause.

This issue is `intermittent` when building on my local machine, I am trying to get CI/CD configured with `Bitrise` and my build `fails consistently` there.

### Log

There's a couple things here that stand out to me.

- `The project declares repositories, effectively ignoring the repositories you have declared in the settings.` - Is there an issue with the way I am including my repos? I've gone through some resources online, and I don't see an issue with my setup.
- `Could not find androidx.compose.compiler:compiler:1.2.0-beta02`

  `Searched in the following locations: https://nodejs.org/dist/v1.2.0-beta02/compiler.jar`

The url being used to find compose.compiler is clearly wrong, why would it be looking in nodejs.org? At first I didn't consider the url a problem, but after I realized it was looking in nodejs, I clicked the link and it returns a 404.

```
> Task :app:writeDebugAppMetadata
> Task :app:parseDebugIntegrityConfig
> Task :app:processDebugManifestForPackage
> Task :app:processDebugResources
> Task :app:mergeExtDexDebug
> Task :app:compileDebugKotlin FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:kotlin-extension'.
  The project declares repositories, effectively ignoring the repositories you have declared in the settings.
  You can figure out how project repositories are declared by configuring your build to fail on project repositories.
  See https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.3/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sub:fail_build_on_project_repositories for details.
   > Could not find androidx.compose.compiler:compiler:1.2.0-beta02.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://nodejs.org/dist/v1.2.0-beta02/compiler.jar
     Required by:
         project :app
* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:74)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:402)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:389)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:382)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:368)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.lambda$run$0(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:127)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:191)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:182)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:124)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:61)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.ResolveExceptionWithHints: Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:kotlin-extension'.
The project declares repositories, effectively ignoring the repositories you have declared in the settings.
You can figure out how project repositories are declared by configuring your build to fail on project repositories.
See https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.3/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sub:fail_build_on_project_repositories for details.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.failuresWithHint(DefaultConfiguration.java:747)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.rethrowFailure(DefaultConfiguration.java:1417)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.access$3600(DefaultConfiguration.java:152)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$DefaultResolutionHost.rethrowFailure(DefaultConfiguration.java:2035)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.visitContents(DefaultConfiguration.java:1395)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.visitContents(DefaultConfiguration.java:498)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.visitStructure(AbstractFileCollection.java:330)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultConfigurableFileCollection.lambda$calculateFinalizedValue$0(DefaultConfigurableFileCollection.java:241)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.UnpackingVisitor.add(UnpackingVisitor.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultConfigurableFileCollection$UnresolvedItemsCollector.visitContents(DefaultConfigurableFileCollection.java:372)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultConfigurableFileCollection.calculateFinalizedValue(DefaultConfigurableFileCollection.java:241)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultConfigurableFileCollection.visitChildren(DefaultConfigurableFileCollection.java:277)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.visitContents(CompositeFileCollection.java:119)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.visitStructure(AbstractFileCollection.java:330)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.lambda$visitContents$0(CompositeFileCollection.java:119)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.UnpackingVisitor.add(UnpackingVisitor.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.UnpackingVisitor.add(UnpackingVisitor.java:89)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFileCollectionFactory$ResolvingFileCollection.visitChildren(DefaultFileCollectionFactory.java:333)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.visitContents(CompositeFileCollection.java:119)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.visitStructure(AbstractFileCollection.java:330)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.lambda$visitContents$0(CompositeFileCollection.java:119)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.PropertyFileCollection.visitChildren(PropertyFileCollection.java:48)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.visitContents(CompositeFileCollection.java:119)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.visitStructure(AbstractFileCollection.java:330)
    at org.gradle.internal.fingerprint.impl.DefaultFileCollectionSnapshotter.snapshot(DefaultFileCollectionSnapshotter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.fingerprint.impl.AbstractFileCollectionFingerprinter.fingerprint(AbstractFileCollectionFingerprinter.java:47)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.fingerprint.impl.DefaultInputFingerprinter$InputCollectingVisitor.visitInputFileProperty(DefaultInputFingerprinter.java:123)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.visitRegularInputs(TaskExecution.java:325)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.fingerprint.impl.DefaultInputFingerprinter.fingerprintInputProperties(DefaultInputFingerprinter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.captureExecutionStateWithOutputs(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:193)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.lambda$captureExecutionState$1(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:141)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildOperationStep$1.call(BuildOperationStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildOperationStep.operation(BuildOperationStep.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.captureExecutionState(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:130)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.lambda$execute$0(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.lambda$execute$2(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:93)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:93)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:31)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.lambda$execute$0(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:40)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution$3.withWorkspace(TaskExecution.java:284)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:30)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:27)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultExecutionEngine$1.execute(DefaultExecutionEngine.java:76)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:142)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:131)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:74)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:402)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:389)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:382)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:368)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.lambda$run$0(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:127)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:191)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:182)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:124)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:61)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not find androidx.compose.compiler:compiler:1.2.0-beta02.
Searched in the following locations:
  - https://nodejs.org/dist/v1.2.0-beta02/compiler.jar
Required by:
    project :app
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 59s
32 actionable tasks: 32 executed
```

### build.gradle (project)

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        kotlin_version = '1.6.21'
        compose_version = "1.2.0-beta02"
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin:secrets-gradle-plugin:2.0.1"
        classpath 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-appsync-gradle-plugin:3.2.1'
    }

}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.0' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

### build.gradle (:app)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin'
    id 'com.amazonaws.appsync'
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ontometrics.repath.officer"
        minSdk 26
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 12
        versionName "12.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
        //freeCompilerArgs += "-Xopt-in=kotlin.RequiresOptIn"
    }

    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }

    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_version
        // kotlinCompilerVersion '1.6.21'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    // AWS SDK
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-appsync:3.3.1'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-apigateway-core:2.44.0'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-mobile-client:2.44.0'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-auth-userpools:2.44.0'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-lambda:2.44.0'

    // Android Core + Compose
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation "androidx.compose.compiler:compiler:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_version"

    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0-alpha01'


    // AWS Chime SDK
    implementation 'software.aws.chimesdk:amazon-chime-sdk-media:0.15.2'
    implementation 'software.aws.chimesdk:amazon-chime-sdk:0.15.2'

    // MyCompanyName VideoChat Library
    implementation("com.mycompanyname:videochat:0.1")

    implementation("io.coil-kt:coil-compose:2.0.0-rc03")
    implementation("com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.44.0")

    api 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.9.0'


    // accompanist
    api "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-permissions:0.22.0-rc"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.4.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.4.0'
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.5.0-beta01"
    implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-systemuicontroller:0.17.0"
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:19.0.1'
    implementation "com.google.maps.android:maps-compose:1.0.0"
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.6.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    testImplementation 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest:2.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_version"
    androidTestImplementation('androidx.test.uiautomator:uiautomator:2.2.0')
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
}
```

### settings.gradle

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

def credentialNotFoundString =
        "\n if you have placed your credential in gradle.properties, it might have been overwritten by mob untility \n\n solution: \n\t place github_user=YOUR_USERNAME and github_token=YOUR_TOKEN in local.properties"

Properties properties = new Properties()
properties.load(new File('local.properties').newDataInputStream())
def localUser
if (user == "GITHUB_USER") {
    localUser = properties.getProperty('github_user')
    if (localUser == null) {
        throw new Exception("github_user not found in ./local.properties" + credentialNotFoundString)
    }
} else localUser = user
def localToken
if (token == "GITHUB_TOKEN") {
    localToken = properties.getProperty('github_token')
    if (localToken == null) {
        throw new Exception("github_token not found in ./local.properties" + credentialNotFoundString)
    }
} else localToken = token

dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
        maven {
            url = uri("https://maven.pkg.github.com/mycompanyname/amazon-chime-example-android")
            credentials {
                username = "$localUser"
                password = "$localToken"
            }
        }
        maven {
            url = uri("https://maven.pkg.github.com/mycompanyname/videochat")
            credentials {
                username = "$localUser"
                password = "$localToken"
            }
        }
    }
}
rootProject.name = "AppName"
include ':app'
```

I can't quite understand why this is so intermittent on my Mac, but fails 100% of the time in Bitrise.

I have tried including the compose compiler as an impementation in the app build.gradle dependencies block, but it still gave the same error.

Comment: You could do a text search in all files (I think it's Ctril + Shift + F or something in the project pane. You could search for the term compiler, or compose compiler. You might find something in the settings.gradle file.

Comment: Unfortunately this was the first thing I tried. :(

Comment: Oh I know how to fix it!! I have edit privileges, so all I have to do is change the first line of the question from "unresolved" to "resolved", and we'll be all good, right? No one will ever know...